# Read Word ActiveX radio button into vb.net form

Tags: vb.net, activex

I'm working on some code to read values in a Word document into a windows form using vb.net.  The word document is designed so that the data to be read in is all contained within content controls.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
Private Sub ImportWordButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImportWordButton.Click
    Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim oCC As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Temp\PIFFormTest2.docx", [ReadOnly]:=False)

    For Each oCC In oDoc.ContentControls
        Select Case oCC.Tag
            Case "PIFNo"
                NumberBox.Text = oCC.Range.Text
            Case "PIFTitle"
                TitleBox.Text = oCC.Range.Text 
            Case "Initiator"
                InitiatorBox.Text = oCC.Range.Text
            Case "PTHealthSafety"
                HealthSafeCheckBox.Checked = oCC.Checked
            Case "PTRegEnviro"
                RegEnvCheckBox.Checked = oCC.Checked
```

... it goes on.  Some of the content in the Word file is captured with ActiveX radio buttons rather than content controls.  I can't seem to find the correct object for referring to the radio buttons. I've spent significant time searching the web.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this too, and it's a nightmare.

```
For Each f As Field In oDoc.Fields    'notice fields not content controls
    Console.WriteLine(f.OLEFormat.Object.Name) 'notice properties, not methods...
Next
```

[Here's the MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838741.aspx)